# Convergence of the sum of fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a function $f$ defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$, $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$, and has continuous first derivative. How can I prove that the sum of the absolute value of the Fourier coefficients converges? The fourier coefficients are defined as $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} \, dx$$

I can bound/ find the convergence of $$\sum |c_n|^2 n^2$$ but I don't know what to do from there or if there is an easier method.

Comment: $\lvert c_n\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\lvert c_n\rvert^2 n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}\bigr)$

Comment: @DanielFischer then, how do we proceed?

Comment: @vidyarthi Then $$\sum_{n \neq 0} \lvert c_n\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\neq 0} \lvert c_n\rvert^2n^2 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n\neq 0} \frac{1}{n^2} < +\infty.$$ Adding $\lvert c_0\rvert$ doesn't make the sum on the left infinite.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the proof for convergence of $\sum_n|c_n|^2n^2$ follows from parseval's identity, isnt it?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes (actually, Parseval is stronger than we need, Bessel's inequality suffices). For $n \neq 0$, we have $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f'(t) e^{-int}\,dt = f(t)e^{-int}\biggr\rvert_{-\pi}^{\pi} + in\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int}\,dt,$$ so $\gamma_n = inc_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ (the case $\gamma_0 = 0$ is done extra), and by Parseval, $\sum \lvert \gamma_n\rvert^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \lvert f'(t)\rvert^2\,dt$.